# Protect Azure logic using oauth and api management

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

Looking for some guidance, links on how i can protect my logic apps using Oauth2 and api management, anyone have some good articles and guides, tried googling around with no real luck

Answer (score 1):

The link given by @derek li is fine to configure the OAuth security on APIM. But after that you need to configure your policy to remove the `Authorization` header.

Otherwise you will receive an error saying:

> The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access scheme.

Check this link for more information: [Secure your Logic Apps with Azure AD and API Management](https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/16/secure-logicapp-with-apim.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with API Management. You can configure your Logic Apps to whitelist and be accessible only by API Management's IPs, and configure API Management to your liking (e.g. Oauth).

For more info, refer to [Securing Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app)

Comment: Yep but the above link has a reference to Api management under section "Adding Azure Active Directory, OAuth, or other security"  but nothing on how to configure this?

Comment: The link in answer specified all the authentication options that Logic App supports. Any of them may be used with Azure APIM. Just create an APIM service and import your Logic App into it (there is a preview functionality for that). By default APIM will use SAS token to call Logic App, that's not something you necessary need to change. If you want to add OAuth on top of that - look into our validate-jwt policy, it would allow you to require oauth token for each request and inspect it's claims.